# Trying to make a table in R where I group columns by variables of a vector

Tags: r, kable, kableextra, gt

I'm trying to generate a neat table using the kableExtra / gt packages (or anything that works), with a goal of having my value columns grouped by the different Variables:

```
data <- data.frame(Name = c("Mary","Mary","Mary","Jane","Jane","Jane"),
                   Variables = c(letters[1:3],letters[1:3]),
                   Count = c(45, 76, 43, 23, 11, 46),
                   Percent = c(0.45, 0.56, 0.89, 0.65, 0.88, 0.91)) %>% arrange(Name, Variables)

# Desired output:
#             a              b               c
#       Count Percent | Count Percent | Count Percent
# Mary   45    45%       76    56%       43    89%
# Jane   23    65%       11    88%       46    91%
```

I can't seem to figure out how to go this, and the closest I can come is:

```
library(gt)
gt(data, rowname_col = "Variables", groupname_col = "Name")
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnM8P.jpg)

I'm taking inspiration that this can be done from the graph shown in [this page](https://rfortherestofus.com/2019/11/how-to-make-beautiful-tables-in-r/):
[table with output columns grouped by year variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDx6H.png)

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**: Solved based on post from Stefan:

```
data <- data.frame(Name = c("Mary","Mary","Mary","Jane","Jane","Jane"),
                   Variables = c(letters[1:3],letters[1:3]),
                   Count = c(45, 76, 43, 23, 11, 46),
                   Percent = c(0.45, 0.56, 0.89, 0.65, 0.88, 0.91)) %>% 
        arrange(desc(Name), Variables)

# Helper to put the columns in the right order
cols_order <- unlist(lapply(c("a", "b", "c"), function(x) paste(x, c("Count", "Percent"), sep = "_")))

data_wide <- data %>% 
        pivot_wider(names_from = "Variables", values_from = c(Count, Percent), names_glue = "{Variables}_{.value}") %>% 
        # Reorder columns
        select(all_of(c("Name", cols_order)))

data_wide %>% 
        gt(rowname_col = "Name") %>%
        tab_spanner_delim(delim = "_") %>%
        fmt_percent(ends_with("Percent"), decimals = 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your desired result you could first reshape your data to wide format using e.g. `tidy::pivot_wider`. Next step is to put the columns in the right order. To this end I reorder the cols of the df but this could probably also be done via `gt`. The remainder is styling the table. To group by `Variables` you could make use of `tab_spanner_delim` and get nicely formatted percentages via `fmt_percent`:

**EDIT** Thanks to **@Shoesoff** for pointing out that my original solution could be simplified considerably by making use of `tab_spanner_delim` instead of `tab_spanner`.

*Improved answer*

```
library(gt)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(Name = c("Mary","Mary","Mary","Jane","Jane","Jane"),
                   Variables = c(letters[1:3],letters[1:3]),
                   Count = c(45, 76, 43, 23, 11, 46),
                   Percent = c(0.45, 0.56, 0.89, 0.65, 0.88, 0.91)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Name), Variables)

# Helper to put the columns in the right order
cols_order <- unlist(lapply(c("a", "b", "c"), function(x) paste(x, c("Count", "Percent"), sep = "_")))

data_wide <- data %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Variables", values_from = c(Count, Percent), names_glue = "{Variables}_{.value}") %>% 
  # Reorder columns
  select(all_of(c("Name", cols_order)))

data_wide %>% 
  gt(data, rowname_col = "Name") %>% 
  tab_spanner_delim(
    delim = "_"
  ) %>% 
  fmt_percent(ends_with("Percent"), decimals = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is perfect!

Comment: Hi Stefan, based on your code I changed a small part at the end that should make this more scalable for a larger dataset with more name variables, and thought I'd share it here:
```
data_wide %>% 
        gt(rowname_col = "Name") %>%
        tab_spanner_delim(delim = "_") %>%
        fmt_percent(ends_with("Percent"), decimals = 0)
```

Comment: Hi Shoesoff. Thanks for sharing. This is reduces the code considerably. I will make an edit to my answer so that it's more useful for others. Best S.

Answer (score 0):

Get the result

```r
data <- data.frame(Name = c("Mary","Mary","Mary","Jane","Jane","Jane"),
                   Variables = c(letters[1:3],letters[1:3]),
                   Count = c(45, 76, 43, 23, 11, 46),
                   Percent = c(0.45, 0.56, 0.89, 0.65, 0.88, 0.91))

v1 <- xtabs(cbind(Count, Percent) ~ Name + Variables, data)
```

Reorganise the data:

```r
Mary <- apply(v1[2,,], 1, c)
dim(Mary) <- NULL
Jane <- apply(v1[1,,], 1, c)
dim(Jane) <- NULL
```

Create the table with kable and add an extra header with kableExtra.

```r
require(knitr)
require(kableExtra)
add_header_above(kable(rbind(Mary, Jane), col.names = rep(c("Count", "Percent"), 3)),
                 c("", "a" = 2, "b" = 2, "c" = 2))
```

[image: Table with two headers]

The rest is a little formatting to add more space and format the percentages...

<sup>Created on 2021-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly for this dataset!